# Make Spheres on a Canvas3D 'clickable'

Tags: geometry, clickable, java-3d, canvas3d

I've got a Canvas3D which holds a couple Spheres. Is there a way to detect when the user clicks on a sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java3D this is known as "Picking" you should read the section on the Java3D API Tutorial if you haven't already. Here is the section on Interacting with objects, you're looking for page 35 by the way:

- http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/j3d_tutorial_ch4.pdf

Heres the entire tutorial:

- http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/

Hopefully this answer didn't come too late! I just started Java3D myself, hope this helped!

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately Java3D questions on StackOverflow seem to not get much attention

Comment: I'm pretty good with Java3D at this point so I'm sure i could answer most of the questions you could come up with, if you're still interested in Java3D